# .size operator in assembly ( stm32 )

Tags: assembly, stm32, cortex-m, eabi

My question is about the use of the .size operator in ARM CORTEX M startup files like this [startup script](https://github.com/tmdarwen/STM32/blob/master/STM32F411/ArmCortexM4Analysis/startup.s).

I have read other questions on the .size operator and my understanding is that the following line :

`.size X,.-X`

allows to define the size of X by the distance between the current location (.) and the definition of the symbol X.

This is ok when this line is used at the end of the X definition. No problem with that.
But how can it work when it is used before the symbol ?

At line 94 of the startup script, you can read :

```
    .section    .isr_vector,"a",%progbits
    .type   g_pfnVectors, %object
    .size   g_pfnVectors, .-g_pfnVectors

g_pfnVectors:
    .word   _estack
    .word   Reset_Handler
    [...]
```

Shouldn't it define a size of -1 ???? How comes it can work ? I guess it's not a mistake since you can find this in all STM32 startup codes ^^

Thanks,

Comment: You are right, it shouldn't work. However maybe nothing depends on that size information being correct. PS: that should define a size of zero, not -1.

Comment: This looks like a defect.

Comment: Oops ! yes you're right, it will define a zero. Now that you say it, it's true that nothing depends explicitly on that size information. I was just not expecting a mistake in code generated by CubeMX. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastien it is not an error. It sets the necessary information needed for proper linking.

Comment: @fuz not the defect

Comment: @Sebastien confusing here is caused by the same name for many different things.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple. `.` (dot) means current address. So the expression (from the github)

```
.size   Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler
```

sets the size of the section Reset_Handler to the current address minus beginng of the section.

Comment: I'm ok with that for the Reset_Handler, and I think I understand the dot notation. My problem is on line 94, when the .size operator is placed _before_ the
g_pfnVectors  symbol ( as shown in the question ) .

Comment: line 96, not 94. Sorry